# I want to add a single value to multiple rows in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Okay suppose I have a data frame A

A:

```
col1 col2
 1    2
 3    4
```

I am not going to add two more columns to it col3 and col4 and want to populate it like so

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
 1    2    5    6
 3    4    5    6
```

All the values of col3 need to be 5 and all the values of col4 need to be 6 no matter the number of rows

is there a way to do this without a loop?

Comment: Simply writing `df['col3'] = 5` and `df['col4'] = 6` will do the trick.

Comment: `df['col3']=5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use assign function:

```
df = df.assign(
    col3 = 5,
    col4 = 6
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple columns with constant values for all rows like below:

```
In [268]: df
Out[268]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     3     4

In [269]: df[['col3', 'col4']] = [5,6]

In [270]: df
Out[270]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     2     5     6
1     3     4     5     6
```

Answer (score 0):

## create `df` with single value per column

This example solves your problem by creating a new `pd.DataFrame` `df1` with a single value per column and concatenates it.

Not the solution I would chose in you case (I think I would go for Mayank Porwal's answer), but I had the usecase for creating such a `df1` and found this answer.

```
>>> df0 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=["col1", "col2"])
>>> df0
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     3     4
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col3": 5, "col4": 6}, index=[0, 1])
>>> df1
   col3  col4
0     5     6
1     5     6
>>> pd.concat([df0, df1], axis=1)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     2     5     6
1     3     4     5     6
```